# Snowflake - Dynamically flattening JSON with unknown shape into table

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have JSON data stored in a `VARIANT` column stored in Snowflake.  The data was ingested through the Kafka Connector to Snowpipe Streaming.  One (1) JSON record per row.  99.9% of the time the keys (columns) are fixed and we know what they are, however, there are times when the upstream processes will introduce a new column and I need to be able to handle it on-the-fly.  My thought is to assume I don't know any of the column names and flatten the JSON accordingly.

How would I flatten the JSON and be able to handle N or N+1 columns (JSON keys)?  Assume the JSON is **not** nested.  All the data in being incrementally loaded into the same table.

Example of data in `VARIANT` column on 1st processing:

| Row # | RECORD_CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "id": "123", "key1": "value1" }` |
| 2 | `{ "id": "456", "key1": "value1" }` |
| 3 | `{ "id": "789", "key1": "value1" }` |

Data inserted into table after 1st processing:

| Row # | id | key1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | value1 |
| 2 | 456 | value1 |
| 3 | 789 | value1 |

Example of data in `VARIANT` column on 2nd processing:

| Row # | RECORD_CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "id": "234", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }` |
| 2 | `{ "id": "567", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }` |
| 3 | `{ "id": "890", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }` |

Data inserted into table after 2nd processing:

| Row # | id | key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | value1 | NULL |
| 2 | 456 | value1 | NULL |
| 3 | 789 | value1 | NULL |
| 4 | 234 | value1 | value2 |
| 5 | 567 | value1 | value2 |
| 6 | 890 | value1 | value2 |

Example of data in `VARIANT` column on 3rd processing:

| Row # | RECORD_CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "id": "321", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }` |
| 2 | `{ "id": "654", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }` |
| 3 | `{ "id": "987", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }` |

(Goal) Data inserted into table after 3rd processing:

| Row # | id | key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | value1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 456 | value1 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 789 | value1 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 234 | value1 | value2 | NULL |
| 5 | 567 | value1 | value2 | NULL |
| 6 | 890 | value1 | value2 | NULL |
| 7 | 321 | value1 | value2 | NULL |
| 8 | 654 | value1 | value2 | NULL |
| 9 | 987 | value1 | value2 | value3 |

I was able to get close with the help of this article, [Creating a snowflake table from Unknown nested json file (Array functions and JSON)](https://medium.com/@databotzero/creating-a-snowflake-table-from-unknown-nested-json-file-array-functions-and-json-b44ffa05b642), but couldn't quite brute force my way to a correct solution.

Comment: You might want to look at `OBJECT_KEYS` function. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_keys

Comment: I wonder if this [preview feature](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-streaming-kafka-schema-detection#configuring-required-kafka-properties) can be applied to your use case.

Comment: The way I would handle this is actually to ingest the json and store it in a variant column table.  Then, create a procedure that looks for all possible key values in the variant column and dynamically create a view over top of the data.  This way, new key value will simply be added to the view for you, and you won't need to keep rebuilding your table.  The view could be materialized, as well, if needed, although any new column would force a re-materialization.